# Using the Facebook Graph API to get a list of a user's friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get a hold of a user of my app's list of friends to filter the users that show up in a friend picker. I know I can call the following and get the list:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=<access_token>
```

I tried it out in the address bar with my own account and it seems to work exactly as I need it to. Problem is, I don't know how to make use of it in a js file itself. I tried calling it and getting the data out with a jquery call but it doesn't seem to return anything helpful.

```
$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends",
    {access_token: <access_token>},
    function(data){ document.write("Data Loaded: " + data);});
```

How should I be calling this in my js files and then actually make use of the information? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As per the [changes introduced in V2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api), `/me/friends` will return **app friends** only.

---

The right way to do that is by using the [Facebook Javascript-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/), something like this:

```
function getFriends() {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        if(response.data) {
            $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
}
```

Please note that:

1. I'm using jQuery here too
2. You may need to check if the user is connected before calling this function.

Comment: Both answers were right but this one wins the prize for sure for the example. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: this solution will only pull those users who have already authorized the application. Anyone got a solution that will pull all users in my friend's list?

Comment: @severinolorillajr, this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract information from the Graph with JavaScript, you will have to use the [JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and [FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) method to make the calls.

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON Sample</title> </head> <body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>   $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/eris.risyana/friends?limit=100&access_token=[your_access_token]', function(mydata) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in mydata.data) {
            output+="<li>NAMA : " + mydata.data[i].name + "<br/>ID : " + mydata.data[i].id + "</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;   });
    </script> </body> </html>
```

**Result :**

```
NAMA : Priscillia Anna Yuliana
ID : 534513444
NAMA : Priyatna Mii
ID : 534619517
NAMA : Icha Sasmita
ID : 544737437
NAMA : CW Trianggono
ID : 599225957
NAMA : Krshna Sulanjana
ID : 605633569
NAMA : Aris Pujiarti
ID : 635209234
NAMA : Armand Muljadi
ID : 663419616
NAMA : Nurdin Somantri
ID : 675697956
NAMA : Muhammad Zamzam Fauzanafi
ID : 686838979
NAMA : Jerome Coutelier
ID : 690661663
```

Comment: @Abhinay: With this approach, I faced issues with the access token and hence started using the JS SDK with my application.

Comment: @Shilpa what I want to know is whether you are able to fetch the entire list of Facebook friends ?