# Is there any good totuiral to facebook API and is it possible to get the friends list of the user in my site?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

1. I want to build a website that you can login with your facebook account.
   what tutorial or any good beginner's book is there on this issue.
2. Is there any good sample of source code for this use
3. can I get the friends lists of my [users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317833/using-the-facebook-graph-api-to-get-a-list-of-a-users-friends) and split it to males and females?
4. what is the difference between GRAPH and Facebook API?

Comment: PHP / JS (not node.js though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Facebook have a few methods for integrating facebook in websites, check out the [Facebook for Websites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) tutorial.
2. You have a few ways to implement this using the tools facebook provides you with, for example you can use the [Registration Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) (you can find code & examples in this tutorial).
3. If you have a facebook application and a user authorizes your app, then you can get the list of his friends. Without asking for specific permissions though all you will get is the their names/facebook ids. If you need more than that check out the [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) documentation (2nd column refers to the friends).
4. Both things are the same, you just gave them different names..  It's called the Graph Api, there's no other "facebook api".  This graph api also supports [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) in case the api alone is not enough for what it is you need.