# use facebook privacy on external sites

Tags: php, facebook

I'm not sure if the title fits.

Let me describe what I'm thinking.

I'm not familiar with facebook API. 
You see, I have this page on a site. And I want this page to be visible only for my friends on facebook. Is there a way I could do that? Like send error 404 if the one viewing is not logged in or not my friend on facebook.

Comment: It's completely doable I'd say. What Web software? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317833/using-the-facebook-graph-api-to-get-a-list-of-a-users-friends

Comment: @PreetSangha just a simple personalized page actually... with contents that I want only my friends on facebook to see... using php, you think this is not possible?

Comment: @PreetSangha Thank you for the link, I'm now getting ideas..

Comment: Not without the user logging in/granting permissions to your usage of the facebook API

Comment: @Scuzzy - I'd say it was a case of a single user auth to the FB (his credentials),  get a list his friends and simple look up or redirect.

Comment: @PreetSangha the friends still need to be logged in to be granted access to the content, just that friends list is coming from a single profile.

Comment: @Scuzzy, do you know if there's a way I could get their fb id without them granting permission using facebook api?

Comment: No, I wouldn't want website being able to get that either.

Comment: @Scuzzy, I found this website which gives you your fb id http://findmyfacebookid.com/ I'm just not sure how they did it... if I know, well, that would answer my post... I will just get their fb id and check if I have that on my friends list.

Comment: @Reigel they used graph api which does provide some basic public details http://graph.facebook.com/mike.tyson but this is obviously requiring user interaction.

Comment: If you are thinking on going forward with the idea to get `id` from profile URL (which user will have to do) and show some private stuff, I would seriously like you to reconsider, as getting the Friend list from account is not a tough job. Instead if you could integrate the `Facebook Login` and then display or restrict the access to page, it would be much more secure.

Comment: you could just database to array your friend list, and when a user has granted basic perms to your application, do an array search against their user id.  Is faster than making a graph api call to do friend check every time the page is loaded.

Comment: Are we talking about a "facebook page" that should contain another tab? I'm not quite getting your "this page on a site".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is very much possible.
You need to make your website and add its URL to a facebook app
(very easy to create a facebook app , just go to the facebook developers and follow the instrcutions).

after u create an app

All you need to do is redirect the user to an OAuth Dialog which will ask the user to accept and add the application giving you the users details.

Here is a simple tutorial to do so https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

after the user accepts it he will be redirected to a URL which u will have to specify (see the tutorial)

or you can do this :

use the facebook php sdk and access the user info this way 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/

In both ways u get the user details and then u can check them against your friends profile details and only allow those users who match it and redirect the rest of the users to any other page using the `header("any.url.com");` command of php.

If u still don't get it please tell me and i will elaborate more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, just make that page to accessed through a script which contains code to get facebook access token and user facebook ID if there is access token & FB ID  than redirect user on the page you wants to display only for your friend. In that page first match the obtained facebook id with the ids of your friends(either stored in db using facebook api). If ids matches with the stored one than load your script other wise redirect it to a 404 html page or to some other url want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible

The obvious way would be using the facebook SDK make your friends log in, But that requires an active log in on your site. Once they are logged in its easy to see if they are on your friends list.

A less obvious way is using something described here
http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/detect-visitor-social-networks/

but combining with your profile in a way which if you get an ok reply (200 status code) on an image you only share with friends, Then have a call back to load another page.

This ISNT foolproof as you rely on javascript not being tampered with but requires less activity from the user

Answer (score 0):

- create a Facebook app, go to the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), click the '+ Create New App' button.
- give your website URL to [Canvas URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)*****
- now you are ready to user facebook API

  ```
  require_once("facebook.php");    
  $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  $config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';        
  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  var_dump($facebook);
  ```

***** There are 2 way to do this.