# Print Facebook friends list from HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am looking to write a quick and dirty script that will pull the names of all my (or someone else's, I suppose) FB friends from the source code of a page with the URL of https://www.facebook.com/USER.ID/friends

Problem is, my knowledge of JS is limited at best.  I basically need to know how to "hone in" on, or target, the text that exists within the link () that exists for each friend within the div with class "fsl fwb fcb".  The only problem I anticipate once I can get to that text is that each link has a different ID beginning with "js_", I suppose I could work around it by parsing the entirety of what's in the div to text and then trimming everything before the first ">" and after the second "<".  But again, no idea how to target those divs in the code.

Once I do that once, I can write a simple loop that will do this for each friend on the page.

Comment: are you familiar with mustache.js (or similar simple templating tools)? Would that be an acceptable way to give you a way to do this?

Comment: That would be scraping, which is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have done this before for my firefox extension .so following js script can get friend data from friends page .

edit : i edited so now this script will print friends name.

```
var frbox=document.getElementsByClassName("fsl fwb fcb");
console.log(frbox.length +"  valid friends");


for(i=0;i<frbox.length;i++){
    var name=frbox[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(name);

}
```

this is dom source code for one friends sector .

[image]

in this code you can see
there is a div and it's class name is 'fsl fwb fcb' .actually it has 3 classes.inside div there is a nested `a` ancer tag .inside open and close tag of this a tags there is friends name example

```
<div class="fsl fwb fcb"><a id="js_8" *more attributes * >Name of a Friend</a></div>
```

so to get friends name in js you

`1)` first select all div s those have classname `fsl fwb fcb`

`2)` loop through the list of selected div and select a one div tag //`frbox[i]`

`3)` select `a` of a div tag

`4)`get `innerHtml` from `a` tag

[this is a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Fn6.jpg) of  script in action .

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, the facebook api does not allow what you are trying to do, unless a person has approved a Facebook api application and entrusts you with the ability to read their entire list of friends.

Read the comments carefully here on the second answer: 
[Using the Facebook Graph API to get a list of a user's friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317833/using-the-facebook-graph-api-to-get-a-list-of-a-users-friends)

Good luck my friend.